# c++ delete dynamic matrix

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic, matrix

I have this code to allocate and initialize:

```
nw = new int*[V];

for (w = 0; w < V; w++) {

nw[w] = new int[K];

for (k = 0; k < K; k++) 

  nw[w][k] = 0;
}
```

and this to free memory:

```
if (nw) {
 for (int w = 0; w < V; w++) {  
  if (nw[w]) 
delete nw[w];      
}
```

The program compile and runs, but, when its try to deallocate memory, fails.
The program not always fails at the same value of w.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated: `delete`ing null pointers has no ill side-effects, so the check is completely redundant and unecessary.

Comment: But if nw = NULL, is "delete[] nw[w];" safe?

Answer (score 8):

When `new[]` use `delete[]`, so change to:

```
delete[] nw[w];
```

and remember to `delete[] nw;`.

Note that the individual assignment of `0` to each `int` in the array can be replaced with:

```
nw[w] = new int[K](); // This value initializes the array, in this
                //^^     case sets all values to zero.
```

You can avoid explicitly handling dynamic allocation with [`std::vector<std::vector<int>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> nw(V, std::vector<int>(K));
```

Comment: I change to: 
delete[] nw[w];

and the error continues.

I make debug and it crash. For some values ​​of w runs well, but not for others

Comment: @user1705996, see http://ideone.com/Ju5MvX for an example. Is `nw` a class member? If so, is it _definitely_ being initialised?

Comment: nw is an atribute of a class:

class model {
public:
...
int ** nw;
...
}

I'm printing the values and all values are 0.

(One think that i don't understand is: for example: I execute it, and it crash when the value of w is 30, and if I execute it another time, crash for a diferent value of w, for example 15 or 40)

Comment: @user1705996, random behaviour is indicative of undefined behaviour. My guess is that `nw` is not being initialised in all versions of the constructor _or_ the object that contains `nw` is being copied and you are using the default copy constructor and default assignment operator (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). My advice is use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Do you know... whats going on if i don't implement the destructor?(when i reboot my computer the memory that i reserved its free?)

Comment: @user1705996, when the program exits the memory will be reclaimed by the OS. However, this is _not_ how to solve this problem. Remove chunks of your code while the error repeats and then start adding parts back in to isolate the cause.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant to use `delete[]`, not `delete`:

```
for (int w = 0; w < V; w++)
    delete[] nw[w];
delete[] nw;
```

Comment: I change to: delete[] nw[w]; and the error continues. I make debug and it crash. For some values ​​of w runs well, but not for others